# Make all Formik fields on init have status 'touched === true'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a Formik form on a page where all fields have errors shown if touched is true and there is an error linked to that field.

However, in some situations I would like to pass a boolean signalling that I want the errors to be shown directly when I show the form. I have already applied validateOnMount to the  component, but, on initiation, I do need to still put the touched status of all fields to true. How can I do this?

```
  <Formik
      key={key}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      validateOnMount
      onSubmit={async values => {}}
      >
          <form>
             {children}
          </form>
  </Formik>
```